# FULLTEXT Irrelevant results

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Just came across this issue using the fulltext search of mysql.

I have like 250 records ( long articles like stuff ) and am using the fulltext `MATCH AGAINST IN BOOLEAN MODE`. Now if I search for a keyword e.g. 'Samsung' and if this keyword is present in ALL the records then it returns all the 250 records which it should ( of course without `IN BOOLEAN MODE it would return nothing as the keyword is present in more than 50% of the records ).

Now the problem is that in some articles the keyword 'Samsung' occurs once and in others a couple of times, but MYSQL is giving a score of 1 to all the records returned, even those which have 'Samsung' like 15 times in them.

Answer (score 3):

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Boolean full-text searches have these characteristics:
 ...
 * They do not automatically sort rows in order of decreasing relevance.

Answer (score 1):

```
select ...
where match(...) against('samsung' in boolean mode)
order by match(...) against('samsung' with query expansion) desc;
```

Comment: I think you're actually running 2 fulltext queries here it might influence performance